# Multiline filter with logspout

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Logspout adds metadata as prefix to every log entry. Now in case of multiline logs, filter works fine and consolidating all the multiline logs into single event but how to get rid of prefix data (metadata) on each log entry.

```
 <14>2015-02-10T12:59:09Z logspout dev_zservice_1[1]:
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
 processing failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException:
 <14>2015-02-10T12:59:09Z logspout dev_zservice_1[1]:    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
 <14>2015-02-10T12:59:09Z logspout dev_zservice_1[1]:    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
 <14>2015-02-10T12:59:09Z logspout dev_zservice_1[1]:    at
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 <14>2015-02-10T12:59:09Z logspout dev_zservice_1[1]:    at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
```

How do I remove metadata from log entries in multiline event?

Comment: Can you share what filters you have already?

Comment: If you want to remove sthg from your logs, you can use the [mutate/gsub filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub).

Comment: To remove `<14>`, you can use `mutate {
    gsub => [
      "message", "<\d+>", ""
    ]
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => [ "message", "<\d+>.*?:\s", "" ] 
    }
}
```

This examines the field "message", selects the substrings from "<14>" to a colon followed by a whitespace, and replaces those substrings with empty strings.